# Vue iterating array from particular index to particular index

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, iteration

Is there any way to iterate array in vue.js from a particular index to another particular index.

for example i have an array with 100 objects,I want to create a view of 30 objects from 30th index to 60th index.

we can make hide remaining index objects with **v-show or v-if** with conditions.but i don't want to do like that.

Any other suggestion.?

Answer (score 4):

Use computed properties  for example

in your component

```
computed:{
    partObject(){
      return this.objects.slice(30,61);
    }
  }
```

now in your component template you iterate over this computed prop

```
 <li v-for="item of partObject">
        {{item}}
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `v-for` to iterate over the indexes and then print the corresponding elements.

Something like this

```
<div v-for="index in 30">{{objects[index+30]}}</div>
```